# c++ and zlib static library

Tags: c++, static, zlib

I am making a c++ (windows devc++) application which downloads a file using libcurl. I have included the libcurl source code and library to mu executable, so no external dll is required. libcurl requires zlib. But I cannot find out how to include it in the executable. As a result zlib1.dll has to be present. Does anybody know how to include this as well? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options.

You said you're using Dev-C++ which compiles using GCC. zlib has a static library option Makefile, just use `make libz.a` and it will produce the static library you desire.

Another option would be to include the zlib source code directly into your application - that means just take the zlib sources and put them inside a dedicated directory in your application's source and set DevC++ to compile it.

Comment: I linked zlib.a at the project option and the removed it from the global option and it work.ed

Comment: I built libz.a but how to build with arm64 arch ? I have to use into iOS static library project.